Can a non-local unitary operator preserve separability
Consider a $2$-qubit system with Hilbert space $\mathcal{H} \cong \mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2$. A pure separable state in $\mathcal{H}$ is of the form $\lvert \psi_1 \rangle \otimes \lvert \psi_2 \rangle$ where $\lvert \psi_i \rangle \in \mathcal{H}_i$. The associated density matrix is $\rho \equiv \lvert \psi_1 \rangle \langle \psi_1 \lvert \otimes \lvert \psi_2 \rangle \langle \psi_2 \lvert$.
Consider a unitary operator $U: \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ that is not of the form $U_1 \otimes U_2$ where $U_i: \mathcal{H}_i \to \mathcal{H}_i$.
Does there exist such a $U$ such that $U\rho U^\dagger = \lvert \psi'_1 \rangle\langle \psi'_1 \lvert \otimes \lvert \psi'_2 \rangle \langle \psi'_2\lvert \equiv \rho'$ where $\lvert \psi'_i \rangle \in \mathcal{H}_i$ and $\rho \neq \rho'$? In words, does there exist a non-local unitary operator that maps a particular pure product density matrix $\rho$ to a distinct pure product density matrix $\rho'$?
I throw out the case in which $\rho = \rho'$ above because it is conceivable that if $U$ stabilizes $\rho$
$$U\rho U^\dagger = \rho,$$
then $U$ could be non-local.

The swap operator preserves separability. It is a non-separable unitary, mapping $\rho$ to $\rho'$, with $\rho \neq \rho'$ and if $\rho$ is separable, then it is $\rho'$ as well.

Is it possible to provide a reference that proves that the SWAP operator is a non-separable unitary? (or prove in your answer if convenient)

An easy way to convince yourself (in a non-rigorous manner) is to think that $\text{SWAP}$ moves information from $\mathcal{H}_2$ into $\mathcal{H}_1$ (and vice versa) for which you need to access information within $\mathcal{H}_2$, which you definitely cannot do if $\text{SWAP}$ is of the form $U_1 \otimes U_2,.$

As for the reference, this paper paper cites this paper saying " the SWAP operation on a bipartite system preserves separability of the bipartite
state, but the SWAP is not separable". I think you should be able to find what you are looking for in second link (although I haven't checked).

@SillyGoose Just compute the rank of SWAP across the A vs B partition.

It’s somewhat interesting that the SWAP gate, which preserves separability of the subsystems, can be decomposed into three CNOT gates, each of which most certainly do not.

Just think about $\text{CNOT}$ gate
$$\text{CNOT} =\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\,.$$
let's say that $\text{CNOT}$ gate could be represented as tensor product $A \otimes B\,.$ Take $$A= \begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{bmatrix}\,\,\,,\,\,\, B=\begin{bmatrix}
e&f\\
g&h
\end{bmatrix}\,.$$
Then $A\otimes B$ is
$$A\otimes B=\begin{bmatrix}
ae & af & be & bf\\
ag & ah & bg & bh\\
ce & cf & de & df\\
cg & ch & dg & dh
\end{bmatrix}\,.$$
Now, considering this is equal to the $\text{CNOT}$, try to compute the value of $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h$. It turns out there is no solution to this.
